# Array of possible values in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following data:

```
letter  number
A       1
A       2
B       3
B       4
C       5
C       6
```

How can I write a select statement in Postgres to select this data into a table with an array of all possible numbers for each letter??

```
letter  number array
A       {1,2}
B       {3,4}
C       {5,6}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select letter, array_agg(number) as numbers
from the_table
group by letter;
```

See also the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html

Answer (score 0):

If your Postgres version doesn't have "array_agg" function, you can try like this:

```
select letter, 
       array( 
              select number 
                from the_table t2 
               where t2.letter = t1.letter
            order by number                   
            ) as numbers
from the_table t1
group by letter;
```

Comment: If his/her Postgres version doesn't have `array_agg` they should plan an upgrade as soon as possible - because it is an unsupported version then.